# SQL. Запрос на выборку из двух связанных таблиц

Tags: sql, запрос

В моей базе данных хранятся две связанные таблицы:

ДолжностьСотрудника:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сотрудник:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(поле *Должность* в таблице Сотрудник ссылается на поле *id_должности* в таблице ДолжностьСотрудника)

Требуется выполнить запрос, в котором необходимо отобразить количество сотрудников по должностям.

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
Директор    1
HR          3
Бухгалтер   2
```

Под цифрами имеется ввиду count сотрудников.
Возникли трудности в составлении такого простого запроса, требуется помощь

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT()

Comment: @Akina, количество можно через коррелированный подзапрос получить, тогда ни JOIN ни GROUP BY в явном виде не понадобятся.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Можно. Но если этот вопрос вообще возник, значит товарищу ещё рано знать о коррелированных запросах в списке вывода, и уж тем более их применять. А то усвоит, что так можно, и будет их втыкать где надо и где не надо... таких порой монстров рожают, что приснится - не отмахаешься... это как выучить INSERT .. VALUES, не освоив до конца INSERT .. SELECT - но увы, все книги и курсы начинают обучение вставке данных не с того конца, и соответственно с таким же плачевным итогом.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов зачем усложнять запрос на 5 строчек корреляцией?

Comment: @ВиталийЗлобин, чтобы отобразить 0 напротив тех должностей, на которых нет ни одного сотрудника.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов в ТЗ не указано на счёт 0, но если нужно, то через LEFT JOIN можно - это будет производительней и удобочитаемо(так же 5 строк), чем для каждой должности ходить в таблицу и считать количество сотрудников на ней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  Название_должности,
        COUNT(*) AS Количество
FROM Сотрудник
JOIN ДолжностьСотрудника ON Должность = id_должности
GROUP BY Название_должности
```